# Eliminating duplicate values in two tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table that records company expenses (Company_Expenses). I also have a table that records employee bonuses (Employee_Bonuses). For obvious reasons, each table has a date, amount and reason\note. The issue is that a bonus given to an employee (Holiday gift, tip, etc...) needs to be recorded as a company expense too. I don't see any logical relation directly between the Bonuses table and the Expenses table other than the fact that a bonus is a company expense. So these three fields (date, amount, reason\note) will be duplicate values in two tables. Is there any way around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bonus is a type of expense. You could make the `EmployeeBonusId` a foreign key referring to `Company_Expenses`, and reuse the `date`, `amount` and `reason` columns. This reduces `Employee_Bonuses` to a very small and simple table that just tracks which employee received which bonus.

EDIT
To clarify, `Employee_Bonuses`' primary key will refer to the `CompanyExpenseID`, and will only hold bonuses. Other expenses will not be listed in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Bonuses (
    EmployeeBonusId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EmployeeID NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeBonusId) REFERENCES Company_Expenses(CompanyExpenseID)
);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying that Employee_Bonuses should be without a PK? Also, the amount of bonuses given a year is a fraction of the amount of expenses so there would be a LOT of NULL values in the Company_Expenses table. This also means that the FK would need to accept NULLS which I didn't know is possible. Maybe I just didn't understand you.

Comment: I agree with @Mureinik, if I understand correctly: `Employee_Bonuses` should consist of three columns: `EmployeeBonusID, EmployeeID, CompanyExpenseID`, with `CompanyExpenseID` constrained to have an appropriate `ExpenseCategoryID`. No NULLs involved.

Comment: @ZviTwersky see my edit, I've attempted to clarify my answer.

Comment: @Dario exactly.

Comment: Still confusing. Dario said that the Employee_Bonuses should have three columns and Mureinik replied @Derio exactly. BUT in Mureinik's EDIT, it only creates TWO columns. Can't figure this out, sorry.

Comment: @ZviTwersky it's a matter of style. Dario's approach is that the bonus table has it's own primary key and another reference back to the expenses table. That would work just fine, but I feel it's a bit redundant, and you could just have the bonus' PK reference the expense directly.

Comment: I usually like PKs and FKs having the same name. Here it won't. You say this won't cause a confusion when I'm into SQL statements?

Comment: @ZviTwersky IMHO, it won't, but again, that's very much an issue of personal style.

Comment: Another issue this would cause (not so much an issue but a thought), If the bonus is the FK, then there cannot be a bonus before there is a company expense. So when I want to give an employee a bonus - I wouldn't be going to some "bonuses" window in my application, but rather Id be going to "company expenses" management, adding a company expense, choosing say "employee bonus" as the category, and only THEN can I add a row in the Bonus table. This seems like a strange workflow.

Comment: @ZviTwersky the table structure should have nothing to do with the application's dialogs. An application constructed around this design would have you go to the bonus dialog and enter its details. Behind the scenes this should create a bonus and the corresponding expense (in the right order, of course).